# Two different versions of WooCommerce product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a new WooCommerce / WordPress site and want to have a catalogue part of the site and shop part.

For each product ( I don't want to duplicate products ) I want:

- Display a page in the shop part *with* E-commerce functionality
- Display a page in the catalogue part *without* E-commerce functionality ( which I could hide with css ).

I don't want to involve the Woocommerce API. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: withoout e-commerce ? are you tring to create marketing pages ?

Comment: No 'Catalogue' pages - so like a regular WooCommerce product page - but without the buy button, link to cart etc - this would be in addition to a regular WooCommerce product page

Comment: can you provide two links (example) that you are expecting ?

eg. 
for product named 'x'
abc.com/product/x/
and 
abc.com/product/catalog/x/

Comment: means when it will have no but buy button some change in URL will be there right ?

Comment: This was achieved by adding the product 'Alina' twice - I want to achieve something similar but by only adding the product one
Alina without e-commerce: http://www.shedcreativedesign.com/madebyzen/?product=alina-ring-fenced

Alina with e-commerce: http://www.shedcreativedesign.com/madebyzen/?product=alina

Comment: Entering a product multiple time is not a good idea..... You can enter one link as it is  - shedcreativedesign.com/madebyzen/?product=alina

and another link as shedcreativedesign.com/madebyzen/?product=alina&catelog=1

now depending on this extra param you can show/hide your buy now button

Comment: yes, thanks, brilliant - would the best way to hide the button in the catalogue page be to use css? and if so how would would the parameter be 'detected' by the css

Comment: no, again css is not the way .... you have to use php code